# Several lines in equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering, line-breaking

I would like to get in LaTeX what the following code produces on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com):

```
$$\pi(X,Y)\to HoM(X,Y)\\\  
[f]\mapsto[RQf]$$
```

[image]

And if I wanted to have an equation number to the right of the two lines, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example (Please observe changing of the meaning of HoM. I am assuming that it is your intention):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\HoM}{Hom}
\begin{document}


The first bijection is induced...
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\pi(X,Y)&\to\HoM(X,Y)\\
[f]&\mapsto[RQf]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
if $X$ is cofibrant and $Y$ fibrant.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `aligned` environment may be a bit of overkill in this case, as there's only a single alignment point. A `split` environment will do the job as well, I think.

Comment: And if I don't want the equation number, I can just use $$...$$ :-)

Comment: @StefanHamcke Oh, I can deduce that you have already read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to :-)

Comment: @StefanHamcke - Actually, using `$$` in a LaTeX document is deprecated; use `\[ ... \]` instead for unnumbered displayed equations. For more information, see the posting [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)